# How to pass Collection through DataContext to UserControl's ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I want to separate ListBox from MainMenu by creating UserControl. In MainWindow I'm creating, for testing purposes, ObservableCollection (in code-behind) and in MainWindow.xaml I'm trying to pass this Collection through DataContext to UserControl

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
ObservableCollection<ListItem> coll = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>() 
{ 
    new TextListItem 
    {
        Content = "Some Text", CreationDate = DateTime.Now, VisibleName = "Title" 
    } 
};
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<userControls:ListBoxUserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=coll}"/>
```

And in **ListBoxUserControl.xaml** I'm trying to access Collection like that

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

But it seems not working. How do I pass Collection through DataContext properly?

Comment: FWIW this is bad practice; you should have proper view models and rarely if ever set `DataContext` on a child control

Comment: I'm still learning, if you could recommend me good MVVM tutorial, that would be great, sir.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coll` should be a property on the `MainWindow` class. As I currently read it, it is just a variable which will go out of scope after you left the method (I think the constructor) in which it is defined.

Comment: Also; `MainWindow` will need its data context set to itself.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET true